# User defined type as scalar of matrix in C++ Armadillo library

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, armadillo

Is there any way to use user defined scalar type inside matrix in Armadillo linear algebra library?
Even `int64_t` type is not working.
This simple declaration `arma::Mat<int64_t> mat;` produces compilation error:

> armadillo_bits\arma_static_check.hpp(23): error C2118: negative
>   subscript armadillo_bits\arma_static_check.hpp(21) : while compiling
>   class template member function 'void
>   arma::arma_type_check_cxx1998::apply(void)'
>   armadillo_bits\mat_meat.hpp(34) : see reference to function template
>   instantiation 'void arma::arma_type_check_cxx1998::apply(void)'
>   being compiled armadillo_bits\mat_meat.hpp(34) : see reference to
>   class template instantiation 'arma::arma_type_check_cxx1998'
>   being compiled armadillo_bits\mat_meat.hpp(17) : while compiling class
>   template member function 'arma::Mat::~Mat(void)'
>   main.cpp(156) : see reference to function template instantiation
>   'arma::Mat::~Mat(void)' being compiled main.cpp(156) : see
>   reference to class template instantiation 'arma::Mat' being
>   compiled

I need matrix with such custom type not for mathematical operations but just for convenient 2d arrays with insert row/column operations, and I don't want to link another library just for these operations. Armadillo is already used in my project.

Comment: To enable 64 bit integers, use either a C++11 compiler, or define `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` before including the armadillo header. Otherwise, manually edit `include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp`.  Explanation of the options is listed in the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp).

Comment: Thank you, but how to use user defined classes? Like arma::Mat<MyLongDouble> mat;

Answer (score 1):

For matrix of integers, [Armadillo uses](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) the following types:

```
umat     =      Mat<uword>
imat     =      Mat<sword>
```